# Cross - compiling Prex

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, makefile, configure

i am trying to compile prex using this guide : [Prex build guide](http://prex.sourceforge.net/doc/build.html)

I want to make a bootable USB out of it and run it pretty much in any computer.

Now, i am using a x86_64 linux system

```
uname -a
Linux xbaremenos 3.19.0-32-generic #37~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 22 09:41:40 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

i run

```
./configure --target=x86-pc --cross-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu-
```

which specifies i want it to build for a x86 platform but when i try to run make i get this message

```
 ~/Downloads/prex-0.9.0 $ make
x86_64-linux-gnu-cpp -D__ASSEMBLY__  -D__x86__ -D__pc__ -DKERNEL -I. -I/home/xbaremenos/Downloads/prex-0.9.0 -I/home/xbaremenos/Downloads/prex-0.9.0/include -I/home/xbaremenos/Downloads/prex-0.9.0/bsp/boot/include -I/home/xbaremenos/Downloads/prex-0.9.0/bsp/boot/x86 x86/pc/head.S x86/pc/head.tmp
x86_64-linux-gnu-as  -o x86/pc/head.o x86/pc/head.tmp
rm -f x86/pc/head.tmp
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc  -c -Os -ansi -pedantic -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -nostdinc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-stack-protector -march=i386 -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-builtin  -D__x86__ -D__pc__ -DKERNEL -I. -I/home/xbaremenos/Downloads/prex-0.9.0 -I/home/xbaremenos/Downloads/prex-0.9.0/include -I/home/xbaremenos/Downloads/prex-0.9.0/bsp/boot/include -I/home/xbaremenos/Downloads/prex-0.9.0/bsp/boot/x86 -o x86/pc/startup.o x86/pc/startup.c
x86/pc/startup.c:1:0: error: CPU you selected does not support x86-64 instruction set
 /*-
 ^
x86/pc/startup.c:1:0: error: CPU you selected does not support x86-64 instruction set
x86/pc/startup.c:1:0: error: -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 is not between 3 and 12
make[2]: *** [x86/pc/startup.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [boot] Error 2
make: *** [bsp] Error 2
```

What am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: are you sure you want the `--cross-prefix` ?

Comment: if a omit it the outcome is the same. At first i tried without it but no luck :(